# In PHPStorm, disable some inspections for tests directory on commit

Tags: scope, phpstorm, code-inspection

I have read through the manual, and can find many options for inspections, but am not able to see how to do what I feel should be rather simple.

I have an inspection profile set up that uses PHPCS to sniff for PSR-2 violations among other things. I also have it setup to run a code analysis everytime I commit. I love this feature because it helps me be sure I'm committing clean code.

The problem is that my tests do not (and in someways cannot) pass those inspections, especially PSR-2. So, every time I make a commit that includes a test file, I get several warnings. This makes the warnings essentially useless because I have to review them each time I commit, and I tend to ignore the warnings all together because I'm sure they are in tests.

So, is there a way to ignore my /tests/ directory in code analysis? Or to setup a different profile for my /tests/ directory? I have tried through the inspections profile, but all I can do is change the severity of the warning, and all levels still show up in my commit. I have also tried excluding /tests/ directory from phpstorm, but then I lose auto completion.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Create custom scope for your `/tests/` folder -- now you can turn on/off specific inspections for that scope.

Comment: I've created a scope for my tests folder, but all I can do is change the severity level. How do I disable tests for a specific scope?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I just figured it out. I was changing the severity. To enable or disable the inspection for a specific scope, you must uncheck the box to the left of "severity warning" for the scope.